# Cancel vertical-align property

Tags: css, styles, vertical-alignment

Is there a way to cancel or overcome a vertical-align property?

I have a website with a stylesheet containing the following CSS:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, 
blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, 
img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, 
center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, 
tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, 
figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary, time, mark, audio, 
video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
```

I have inserted a table on a page with its content showing up in a weird way because of this style property (meaning that if I uncheck "vertical-align: baseline" within Chrome developer tool, it shows up exactly how I want).

How can I reproduce that on my page?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't `baseline` the default for tables anyway?. Demo needed I think since "weird" is undefined.

Comment: Baseline is default indeed. However, removing this property, changes quite a lot the look and feel of the table I am working on. I've tried to change the "baseline" property to something else but it doesn't seem to be working..

Comment: I had the exact same problem with a mat-datepicker where the numbers shifted out of the table only in firefox, only on certain months. Finally found out that the vertical-align: baseline in the reset was the culprit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an interesting question because it touches very much on the default style sheet of the browser.

If you look at the default style sheet given in the spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html), you see the following:

```
thead, tbody,
tfoot           { vertical-align: middle }
td, th, tr      { vertical-align: inherit }
```

As a result, the default behavior is for the content of a table-cell to be vertically centered in the table cell.

In your style sheet, you are setting the vertical-align property to `baseline` for the `tbody`, `tfoot`, `thead`, `tr`, `th` and `td` elements, which is affecting your table layout.

You need to either adjust the CSS rule that resets the vertical-align property or add additional rules for the table styling as needed.

In your example, you can simply add the two rules given above after your 
original rule.

Alternatively, leave out the vertical-align property from the original rule set.

To be more specific, alter your CSS style sheet as follows:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, 
blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, 
img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, 
center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, 
tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, 
figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary, time, mark, audio, 
video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
thead, tbody, tfoot { vertical-align: middle } /* add this rule*/
td, th, tr { vertical-align: inherit } /* add this rule */
```

by adding the two additional rules.

Comment: Yes exactly! But so, what rules are these? As I said above, I've tried more or less all the vertical-align rules I could to reset the stylesheet. This is where I struggle to get it changed.

Comment: I updated my answer to be more explicit.  Either add two additional CSS rules to reset the default vertical-align property value or omit it from the original rule.  Alternatively, remove all table element tags from the reset rule if you are happy with the default table behavior, specifically, `tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td`.

Comment: I've tried on JSFiddle and it works perfectly! Thanks for that answer. However, prob is that I can't edit the stylesheet (I don't have this level of administration).
Therefore, I've added these two lines directly on the page. Problem is that even if I try to force it adding "!important", it doesn't look like it's working properly. Is there a subtilityI am missing here?

Comment: Ah well, it seems to be working by changing the second rule from "inherit" to "middle" similarly to the first one. Thanks a lot Marc!

Comment: This is not sufficient in the general case, since `sup` and `sub` also have default `vertical-align` different from `baseline`. Moreover, browsers *may* have any default settings they like, and there can also be user style sheet affecting the situation (and other page style sheets).

Answer (score 1):

i am also using a wordpress template with the same "reset" in the stylesheet.
i didn't want to simply reset the reset in my child stylesheet -- untold number of errors that could cause, based on the convoluted css.
instead, in my "child" stylesheet, i added a class and defined that any table element within a item sporting that class would be vertically aligned to the middle:

```
.masthead-table table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

then in the page where it actually appears, i gave the div containing the table its proper class:

```
<div class="masthead-table">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        voila, my middle-v-aligned content
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cancel a property. By CSS principles, every element has all properties defined in CSS (though not all properties affect the rendering of an element).

Neither can you tell, in a style sheet, a browser to ignore a CSS rule appearing in another style sheet. You can only throw in your own settings, and they will then participate the cascade and may thereby override other settings.

There is no way to know what CSS settings may be present in browser default style sheets, user style sheets, and other page style sheets. The only way to ensure that things work as if a CSS rule were not present is to actually remove the rule. This is one reason why “CSS reset” rule sets are so risky.

If you have been forced to work in an environment where some “CSS reset” is present and cannot be removed or changed, you may need to study in detail which default settings they may override. There is no guarantee that this is successful, since browsers are free to have whatever they like in the default style sheets. But the settings that *probably* matter are those that are described and more or less recommended in HTML5, section [Rendering](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#rendering). It describes the following:

```
sub { vertical-align: sub; }
sup { vertical-align: super; }
thead, tbody, tfoot, table > tr { vertical-align: middle; }
tr, td, th { vertical-align: inherit; }
```

... and some settings that define the `valign` attribute in terms of CSS, as well as some special rules for the new `meter` and `progress` elements.

Thus, `vertical-align: baseline` may cause several default rendering features to be overridden. You would need to analyze which of them apply and to make sure that you set `vertical-align` to suitable values for the elements where it matters.

Answer (score 0):

Since vertical-align property cannot be canceled, will your website render appropriately without it? Like by modifying margin, padding, and border?
   margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px; (or something similar)....

A very descriptive site for info on those:
   http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html

And this site for info on baseline and vertical-align:
   http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-text-3/

Answer (score -1):

Please check [CSS vertical-align property default](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)
because the default value is baseline anyway.
However, you can remove it from the CSS set,

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that simple as I don't want to mess up with other parts of the website. I need to remove or counter the CSS property for a page only.

Comment: The default vertical-align property value has a non-trivial setting for tables, see my answer.